# How do I fill a polygon formed by 3 different sets of arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I see that fill_between() requires a single x-range. But in my case I have 3 sets of arrays that span different ranges on the x-axis. These curves join at the ends to form a polygon. For example:

```
x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [5,4,3,2,1]

x2 = [1,3,5,6,7]
y2 = [5,6,7,8,9]

x3 = [7,6.5,7,8,5]
y3 = [9,8,8,6,1]

plt.plot(x1,y1,
         x2,y2,
         x3,y3)
```

[image]

My real arrays have a length of 1000, however, so this is just a simplified example to clarify my question. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shapely` to concatenating line segments automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import linemerge

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [5,4,3,2,1]

x2 = [1,3,5,6,7]
y2 = [5,6,7,8,9]

x3 = [7,6.5,7,8,5]
y3 = [9,8,8,6,1]    

l1 = LineString(zip(x1, y1))
l2 = LineString(zip(x2, y2))
l3 = LineString(zip(x3, y3))
l = linemerge([l1, l2, l3])
x, y = l.coords.xy
plt.fill(x, y)
# or plt.fill_between(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`plt.fill`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html) to draw a filled polygon. Just concatenating the lists to create a closed polygon suffices. Note that all the segments need to be consecutive, so the first segment needs to be reversed to fit together with the other two. The polygon can be convex, concave or even self-intersecting.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [5,4,3,2,1]

x2 = [1,3,5,6,7]
y2 = [5,6,7,8,9]

x3 = [7,6.5,7,8,5]
y3 = [9,8,8,6,1]

plt.plot(x1[::-1]+x2+x3, y1[::-1]+y2+y3, c='navy')
plt.fill(x1[::-1]+x2+x3, y1[::-1]+y2+y3, c='crimson', alpha=0.3)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider accepting the answer to let others know the question has been solved.